# how do i know which mongodb instance meteor.js connects to?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I think I have multiple instances of mongo available on my laptop. How do I know which instance meteor connects to. Also, is there a way to get into the shell of that instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default meteor will automatically use its built in Mongo client. If you are connecting to this you can access its shell by calling `meteor mongo` whenever your meteor application is running·

To test which database is being accessed you can access the MONGO_URL environment variable which is set when you launch your application. Adding a `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);` somewhere within your server side codebase should trigger it to be printed to the terminal.